# How to populate a collection in java?

Tags: java

Suppose we are creating a class in java where name and code are two private members and then are passing them in the list.

```
 class A
 {
           private int code;
           private string name;
           public getCode()
              { return code;}
            public setCode(int code){this.code=code;}
            public getName()
                  { return name;}
           public setName(String name){this.name=name;}
```

---

```
class B {
            List<A> l1=new List<A>
```

Now how to populate list A?

Comment: [`l1.add(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-)

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do here... if the question is how to add to a list collection try `l1.add(new A())`

Comment: could you clarify a bit more? Exactly what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A obj = new A();
obj.setCode(123);
obj.setName("test");

List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `l1.add(new A())`. This will add a new instance of class `A` to your list, `l1`.

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-